# htaccess 301 redirect append last part of the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I use htaccess to do redirect to another url while keeping last segment of the url.

ex:

**Redirect from**
http://xyz.mysite.com/signup/202 (202 is dynamic and can change)

**to** 
http://mysite.com/somewhere/202

I searched allot but couldn't find anything related to this. Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in **xyz.mysite.com**'s document root, using mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /signup http://mysite.com/somewhere
```

using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?signup/(.*)$ http://mysite.com/somewhere/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's explicitly documented in the Apache HTTPD mod_rewrite documentation. There's even an example of exactly what you're attempting.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html